# Flutter audioplayer Exception

Tags: android, flutter

Does anyone know where this exception come from, I just making a game and every click has a sound, isn't a problem for sounds to interfere? I created a class call playaudio importing audioplayer and audiocache with play and pause methods, and instantiate it when I need it.
Note: this error is happening rarely, because I'm using Timer to automate the game so it happening just in some points.

[Flutter audio player Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8Ilw.png)

[My playaudio Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qop6.png)

Answer (score 1):

Update:
I was facing this error because I was automatically runs multiple sounds in the same time, after adding some conditions lines to dominate one sound upon others, for example to prioritize win sound effect upon the restart sound effect like:

```
if (!win){
            play(restartSound)
         }
```

That's what solved my problem.